# Carbon add days to next monday

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have Carbon date variable.

```
Carbon::parse("2018-08-01") //tuesday
```

I want to add days until next `monday ("2018-08-07")`.

Is there command like

```
 Carbon->addDaysUntil("monday"); ->addMonthUntil("september")
```

and so on.

So i want to change current date to begining of next week, month, year

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you can do is determine the current date, get the start of the week (Monday) and add a week to get the next week.

```
$date = Carbon::create(2017, 8, 30);
$monday = $date->startOfWeek();
$mondayOneWeekLater = $date->addWeeks(1); // $date->addWeek();
```

Rinse and repeat for months and years but as Maritim suggests it's in the docs. ;-)
Source: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 44):

Old question but there's a nice way of doing this at the moment.

```php
$date = Carbon::parse('2018-08-01')->next('Monday');
```

Additionally, if you want to check if your date is monday first, you could do something like this:

```php
$date = Carbon::parse(...);
// If $date is Monday, return $date. Otherwise, add days until next Monday.
$date = $date->is('Monday') ? $date : $date->next('Monday');
```

Or using the Carbon constants as suggested by @smknstd in the comment below:

```php
$date = Carbon::parse(...);
// If $date is Monday, return $date. Otherwise, add days until next Monday.
$date = $date->is(Carbon::MONDAY) ? $date : $date->next(Carbon::MONDAY);
```

Comment: thanx for sharing because it's not easy to find this in Carbon documentation. I found out you can use const instead of strings as parameter:

`Carbon::now()->next(Carbon::MONDAY);`

Comment: Is also possible to write using ->isMonday(): $date = $date->isMonday() ? $date : $date->next(Carbon::MONDAY);

Comment: `is()` function compares integers with year, so `$date->is(Carbon::MONDAY)` won't work because `Carbon::MONDAY` is integer `1`; It will only work if we do `$date->is('monday')`; we can check weekday by `$date->weekday() === Carbon::MONDAY`.